# CUDA: variable declaration within threads--is there overlap?

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

First off, my question isn't worded correctly; I think it's better if I ask using an example found in NVidia's CUDA C Programming guide.

In section 3.2.3 (Shared Memory), the following code is given for Matrix Multiplication using shared memory--I hope it's okay for me to copy it here.

```
__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
// Block row and column
int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
int blockCol = blockIdx.x;

// Each thread block computes one sub-matrix Csub of C
Matrix Csub = GetSubMatrix(C, blockRow, blockCol);

// Each thread computes one element of Csub
// by accumulating results into Cvalue
float Cvalue = 0;

// Thread row and column within Csub
int row = threadIdx.y;
int col = threadIdx.x;

// Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B that are
// required to compute Csub
// Multiply each pair of sub-matrices together
// and accumulate the results
for (int m = 0; m < (A.width / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m) {

    // Get sub-matrix Asub of A
    Matrix Asub = GetSubMatrix(A, blockRow, m);

    // Get sub-matrix Bsub of B
    Matrix Bsub = GetSubMatrix(B, m, blockCol);

    // Shared memory used to store Asub and Bsub respectively
    __shared__ float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    __shared__ float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

    // Load Asub and Bsub from device memory to shared memory
    // Each thread loads one element of each sub-matrix
    As[row][col] = GetElement(Asub, row, col);
    Bs[row][col] = GetElement(Bsub, row, col);

    // Synchronize to make sure the sub-matrices are loaded
    // before starting the computation
    __syncthreads();

    // Multiply Asub and Bsub together
    for (int e = 0; e < BLOCK_SIZE; ++e)
        Cvalue += As[row][e] * Bs[e][col];

    // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
    // computation is done before loading two new
    // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
    __syncthreads();
}

// Write Csub to device memory
// Each thread writes one element
SetElement(Csub, row, col, Cvalue);
}
```

On the 7th line: Matrix Csub = GetSubMatrix(C, blockRow, blockCol), will every thread execute that statement? Wouldn't that nullify the whole point of using shared memory to reduce the amount of global memory accesses? I'm under the impression that there's something fundamental that I'm missing here..

Also, there's certainly a better way to word this question. I just don't know how!

Thanks,

Zakiir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread executes the same instruction at the same time (or is idle), so every thread goes into `GetSubMatrix` yes. Each thread takes a few items. So if there are `N` threads and `3N` items to be copied each thread will copy 3.

For example, if I were copying a vector, I might do the following

```
float from* = ???;
float to*   = ???;
int   num   = ???;
int   thread = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*blockDim.x ...; // A linear index
int   num_threads = blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z;
for(int i=threadIdx.x; i < num; i+= num_threads) {
     to[i] = from[i];
}
```

Every thread is involved in copying one bit at a time. As an aside: if you can manage to get all the threads to copy a sequential bunch of elements you get bonus speed in the copy.

Comment: I understand that each thread will load one element of each sub-matrix A and B, and when that's finished, all of the threads in the block will be able to read each others shared memory for the partial matrix multiplication. I'm still confused as to why each thread needs to create it's own C sub-matrix because each thread only writes one element.

Comment: Have you got access to GetSubMatrix? It's possible it's just copying address locations and not copying the elements themselves. If that's the case then each thread will get a copy of the Matrix structure/class. Everyone doing it will save a `__syncthreads()`, and won't cost any more than one thread doing it (each thread must run the same instruction at the same time).

Comment: GetSubMatrix returns a Matrix, Csub which is a portion of the final product matrix; Matrix is a struct that's defined earlier in the code.

Comment: Right, but does it actually copy the elements or just calculate appropriate offsets from the original matrix?

Comment: The struct has the following information:
`code:
int numcols;
int numrows;
int stride;
float* elements;
`
My understanding is that it calculates the offsets from the original matrix. So yes, I think you're right!